# Finding Mac address for Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, mac-address

I'm getting error messages by running this python script to get Mac address.This is working very fine with python 2.7 but for python 3.6its throwing error.

```
import subprocess, re
listOutputMAC = 0
def mac_list():
    output = subprocess.check_output("getmac")
    print(output)
    regex = r"([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})"
    matches = re.finditer(regex, output)

    listOutputMAC = []
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
        matchNum = matchNum + 1
        listOutputMAC.append("{match}".format(matchNum=matchNum, start=match.start(),
                                              end=match.end(), match=match.group()))
    print(output)
    return listOutputMAC

var1 = mac_list()
print(var1)
```

This is my Error log :
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "s.py", line 19, in <module>
    var1 = mac_list()
  File "s.py", line 9, in mac_list
    matches = re.finditer(regex, output)
  File "C:\Users\Cookie1\Anaconda3\envs\py3\lib\re.py", line 229, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Comment: Your regex is a string, you are trying to match it against a bytes value. Convert one or the other.

Comment: `regex = br"([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})"` would work in both Python 2 and 3 to make the regex the correct type for both versions.